# On Github, merging PR into different branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

Say someone submits a PR to public/master on Github.

Is there a way to merge that PR into a different branch? Otherwise, looks like I have to merge into public/master, then merge that backwards into a development/staging branch. It's like having people do a hotfix and then merging the hotfix into a development branch, which is something we normally should want to avoid right?

Seems to make more sense to have people track and submit PRs to a staging/development branch instead of master.

What is the best way to do that? The tricky part is that currently the staging/development branches are private. Sounds like I have to make one development branch public, and then direct people to branch from and submit PRs to that branch?

Comment: You should regularly be merging master in to any feature branches. I don't see what the issue is here. `master` is supposed to be the most up to date **stable** branch. It's not always going to be the bleeding edge. As long as the PR looks good, has tests and everything is passing there is no reason to not merge to master.

Comment: Eh, but wouldn't it be *preferable* to merge into a development branch instead of directly into master? What you're saying resembles a hotfix, which is not preferable, for most software teams.

Comment: Is there a reason your development branch can't be public?

Comment: There's just a bunch of relatively private files on there, that ideally only the development team would see, not just anybody who could submit a PR. But yeah, otherwise, I could put the dev branch on the public remote. And people could submit PRs to that instead of master.

Comment: No it doesn't. Feature branches get added to master as part of the normal development process all the time, especially on larger teams. If you don't have a process for vetting PR's against your public branch before merging them you shouldn't have that branch accepting PR's from the public. If your tests aren't good enough or your CI process isn't good or doesn't exist you need to fix that first.

Comment: I agree with that. I just think it's more ideal to merge into a development branch first. Merging from master back into a dev branch to capture the PRs is just something to avoid IMO. Which is the ultimate purpose of the original question. How to avoid that. For example, what if you did major refactoring on the dev branch, and it hasn't merged into master yet.

Comment: the downvote was unnecessary and it looks like @ScottWeldon provided a reasonable answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, you can't target a PR for a branch that you don't know exists.

Your history might look something like this:

```
*--A--B--C [develop] (private)
    \
 ... D--*--*--E [master]
               \
                F--G--H--I [myfeature] (PR for this)
```

There are two problems here. (1) The PR for `myfeature` can't target `develop`, because `develop` is private, and not visible to the author of `myfeature`. (2) The `develop` branch has some commits (in this case `B` and `C`) that are also private.

The second problem is the more important one. If commit `B` conflicts with commit `G`, then no matter how you try to get the changes from `myfeature` into `develop`, *you* will have to be the one to resolve that conflict. This is not ideal; I have found that it is much easier for the author of the PR to have the responsibility of resolving conflicts, rather than the maintainer.

With that said, there are two solutions: go public, or rebase and merge.

### Go Public

This is the solution that I recommend, because it will be the easiest long-term solution. You can push your `develop` branch to GitHub and make it public. This would allow other users to branch off of `develop` and send PRs against it.

You mentioned that you have certain private files in your `develop` branch. Depending on what you need those files for, you may be able to `ignore` them, or extract sensitive values out of them to be loaded at runtime. It is best to never have private files anywhere in your repo, because among other reasons, you may accidentally make `develop` public.

If you use this solution, then you are already pretty close to using the [Git Flow](//github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) workflow, which I also recommend.

### Rebase and Merge

If you absolutely can't make `develop` public, then you need to rebase and merge. First, do:

```
git rebase --onto develop master myfeature
```

Your history will now look like this:

```
           F'--G'--H'--I' [myfeature]
          /
*--A--B--C [develop]
    \
 ... D--*--*--E [master]
               \
                F--G--H--I
```

You can then merge into `develop` as normal:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff myfeature
```

Giving you:

```
           F'--G'--H'--I' [myfeature]
          /             \
*--A--B--C---------------J [develop]
    \
 ... D--*--*--E [master]
               \
                F--G--H--I
```

The other downside of this solution is that as far as GitHub is concerned, the PR hasn't been merged yet, so you'll have to close it manually. Related to this, the user who submitted the PR won't be able to see that it has been merged until you release new changes from `develop` to `master`.