# Will github merge this PR into ''master' branch even though the PR is created against another feature branch?

Tags: github, merge

*It is not the same as the situation outlined in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477092/on-github-merging-pr-into-different-branch)  so please restrained from marking this one as  duplicate without reading the content first.*

During my development, I created branch A from the master branch for some dev work.

Then from branch A I created branch B and added a few more commits (says commit C1 and C2).

The reason is being that I want to create a PR for branch B which will ONLY show C1 and C2. However the CI build will use all changes in branch A plus C1 and C2 to run the integration test.

Now I have already merged the branch A into master, and I am ready to merge B.

Now looking at the github's 'Confirm squash and merge' button,

[image]

I am not entirely sure what will happen:

*Will github try to merge C1 and C2 in branch B into branch A (which is already deleted after its merge), or will github try to merge C1 and C2 into **master**?*

Comment: In the PR you can check the commits/changes that would be merged, and at the top there's a line which tells which branch it will be merged into.

Comment: I wanted to change it to master. Is it possible?